# Splitting X_train into two dataframes based on y_train values

Tags: pandas

I have the following function that looks at the value for each row of y_train, a single column and is either 0 or 1, and based on that it will put each corresponding X_train row into either Tmaj or Tmin. But I am not getting the indexing right, or maybe  there is a better method.

```
def fun(X_train,y_train):
    Tmaj = pd.DataFrame()
    Tmin = pd.DataFrame()

    row=0
    for each in y_train['Outcome']:
        if each==1:
            Tmaj.append(X_train.loc[[row]])
        #else:
            #Tmin.append(X_train.loc[[]])
        row+=1
```

Comment: You don't need the loop for, just do `Tmaj = X_train[y_train['Outcome'].eq(1)]`? and `append` on a dataframe is not like on a list, you would need to reassign `Tmaj = Tmaj.append(...`, but it is not a good practice to use `append` on a dataframe in a loop for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the loop just index `X_train` with a boolean mask

```
def fun(X_train, y_train):
    Tmaj = X_train.loc[y_train.Outcome==1, :]
    Tmin = X_train.loc[y_train.Outcome==0, :]
    return Tmaj, Tmin
```